# Summation without a for loop - MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have 2 matrices: **V** which is square MxM, and **K** which is MxN. Calling the dimension across rows `x` and the dimension across columns `t`, I need to evaluate the integral (i.e sum) over both dimensions of **K** times a t-shifted version of **V**, the answer being a function of the shift (almost like a convolution, see below). The sum is defined by the following expression, where `_{}` denotes the summation indices, and a zero-padding of out-of-limits elements is assumed:

```
S(t) = sum_{x,tau}[V(x,t+tau) * K(x,tau)]
```

I manage to do it with a single loop, over the `t` dimension (vectorizing the `x` dimension):

```
% some toy matrices
V = rand(50,50);
K = rand(50,10);
[M N] = size(K);

S = zeros(1, M);            
for t = 1 : N
  S(1,1:end-t+1) = S(1,1:end-t+1) + sum(bsxfun(@times, V(:,t:end),  K(:,t)),1);                
end
```

I have similar expressions which I managed to evaluate without a for loop, using a combination of `conv2` and\or mirroring (flipping) of a single dimension. However I can't see how to avoid a for loop in this case (despite the appeared similarity to convolution).

Comment: What are the summation limits on tau? I guess I could figure it out with your code...

Comment: It doesn't really matter as long as it covers all non-zero elements of V (as I said, V is assumed to be zero-padded to the left and to the right)

Comment: Your code gives me the error `Error using  + Matrix dimensions must agree.`

Comment: Sorry, S should be [1,M]. Fixed it. (thanks for pointing it out).

Comment: Just looking at this again, I'm still a little bit confused. There seems to be a discrepancy between your formula and your code --- in the former, the `t`'th entry of `S` depends only on the `t`'th column of `K`, but in the latter, this seems to no longer be true.

Comment: No, in the formula it depends as well on `V[x,t+tau]` so it does have an explicit `t` dependency.

Comment: I never denied that it had explicit `t` dependency. All I'm saying, e.g., is that in the formula `S(1)` doesn't depend on `K(5,2)`, but in the code it does. There must be a typo somewhere.

Comment: Again, you are correct... it should be `K(x,tau)` not `K(x,t)`. Fixed it (thanks again).

Comment: I've tried to vectorize, but I still need a for loop to vectorize the V matrix:  
`V = rand(50,50);`  
`K = rand(50,10);`  

`Kdim = repmat(permute(K,[1 3 2]),1,50);`  
`index = repmat(repmat([50:-1:1],50,1),[1 1 10])>=repmat(permute(1:10,[3 1 2]),50,50);`  
`Vdim = repmat(V,[1 1 10]);`  
`for i = 1:size(Vdim,3)`
`Vdim(:,:,i) = circshift(V,[0 -i+1]);`  
`end`  
`this = bsxfun(@times,Vdim.*index,Kdim);`
`S = sum(sum(this,1),3)`
If somebody knows how to vectorize V to Vdim without the for loop, we have the solution...

Comment: @reverse_engineer Or use matrix-multiplication and some boolean indexing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps to vectorization**

1] Perform `sum(bsxfun(@times, V(:,t:end),  K(:,t)),1)` for all columns in V against all columns in  K with matrix-multiplication -

```
sum_mults = V.'*K
```

This would give us a 2D array with each column representing `sum(bsxfun(@times,..` operation at each iteration.

2] Step1 gave us all possible summations and also the values to be summed are not aligned in the same row across iterations, so we need to do a bit more work before summing along rows. The rest of the work is about getting a shifted up version. For the same, you can use boolean indexing with a upper and lower triangular boolean mask. Finally, we sum along each row for the final output. So, this part of the code would look like so -

```
valid_mask = tril(true(size(sum_mults)));
sum_mults_shifted = zeros(size(sum_mults));
sum_mults_shifted(flipud(valid_mask)) = sum_mults(valid_mask);
out = sum(sum_mults_shifted,2);
```

---

Runtime tests -

```
%// Inputs
V = rand(1000,1000);
K = rand(1000,200);

disp('--------------------- With original loopy approach')
tic
[M N] = size(K);
S = zeros(1, M);
for t = 1 : N
    S(1,1:end-t+1) = S(1,1:end-t+1) + sum(bsxfun(@times, V(:,t:end),  K(:,t)),1);
end
toc

disp('--------------------- With proposed vectorized approach')
tic
sum_mults = V.'*K; %//'
valid_mask = tril(true(size(sum_mults)));
sum_mults_shifted = zeros(size(sum_mults));
sum_mults_shifted(flipud(valid_mask)) = sum_mults(valid_mask);
out = sum(sum_mults_shifted,2);
toc
```

Output -

```
--------------------- With original loopy approach
Elapsed time is 2.696773 seconds.
--------------------- With proposed vectorized approach
Elapsed time is 0.044144 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be cheating (using `arrayfun` instead of a `for` loop) but I believe this expression gives you what you want:

```
S = arrayfun(@(t) sum(sum( V(:,(t+1):(t+N)) .* K )), 1:(M-N), 'UniformOutput', true)
```